# Compare two date in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utc

I have a date which is coming from the form in American format (MM-DD-YYYY) and now i want to compare it with the date from the database which is in utc.
 And therefore i have to convert that date to utc,I'm doing this but its not working:

```
from_date = Date.strptime(params[:from_date], '%m-%d-%Y').utc
```

It is giving me error

```
undefined method `utc' for Sat, 15 Dec 2012:Date
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#utc` method is only defined for Time objects. If timezones are important for what you are trying to do, try

```
from_date = Date.strptime(params[:from_date], '%m-%d-%Y').to_time.utc
```

Also look at the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-utc